# How to create a Line Item with vertical middle aligned text?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am having trouble creating line items with the following requirements:

- Line items contain: top/left aligned icon, title, and optional subtitle
- Text should be vertical align middle
- Width of the container is dynamic

Here is a Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6ug3314b/

Problem:

I cannot figure out how to get this CSS to work without hard coding the width of something. See the JS Fiddle link above.

I can't figure out how to get the ".licontent" div from wrapping to the next line without knowing the width of the container.

Here is the CSS so far:

```
.lineItems {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.lineItems > li {
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}

.lineItems .title {
    margin: 0;
}

.lineItems .licontent {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.lineItems .icon {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.lineItems .icon:after {
    content: 'ICON';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight forward, if I understood correctly. You just need to add a % based width that works and a @media inquiry to reduce the % as needed since the image isn't also percentage based.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L1b8n04j/)

```
.lineItems .licontent {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
padding-left: 10px;
width:85%;
word-break: break-word;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
    .lineItems .licontent {width:73%}
}
```

Comment: There is no way to know that the container width is the same as the screen width.

Comment: This might work as well, although there will be some unused space on the right side of the line items.

Comment: @codefactor Play around with the percentages and you can usually minimize that space. Also, in terms of design aesthetics, it's better for the words to have some spacing from the edge of the container. Especially if you intend to have some type of border or background color. Best of luck.

Comment: I am marking this one as the accepted answer that I chose to go with - The table-cell approach in the other answer seemed too fragile. I think I can live with some unnecessary white space on the right hand side. I tried it out on the real page and added one additional media query (for added precision for larger widths) it looks pretty good. In my favor is the fact that this is for mobile screens, so usually the widths are not that big.

Comment: @codefactor Why do you say "table-cell is too fragile"? By the way, I assume you're using Safari/Chrome, `word-break: break-word;` is non-standard and only works on WebKit based browsers, check the above demo out on Firefox you'll see.

Comment: I'll take a closer look when I get some time - maybe the word "fragile" is the wrong word for it. In my mind I was thinking the use of display "table-cell" on a div seemed non-standard. I said "fragile" because I was associating non-standard with a possibility of not working in some browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like CSS `table` and `table-cell` could be a great solution. It supports both unknown width and vertical-align.

And use `table-layout: fixed;` + `word-wrap: break-word;` for wrapping long lines.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/pn5pja7e/

```
.lineItems {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.lineItems > li {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed; /*NEW*/
    word-wrap: break-word; /*NEW*/
}

.lineItems .licontent {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 10px;
    /* word-break: break-all; */
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.lineItems .title {
    margin: 0;
}

.lineItems .icon {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.lineItems .icon:after {
    content: 'ICON';
}
```

Comment: Close, but a couple of issues with your fiddle: 1) Line items do not appear to be taking up full width, 2) The long text with no spaces doesn't wrap, 3) The icon needs to be fixed 50x50 but seems to change size

Comment: Your edited demo looks better - I will look at it more closely.

Comment: The break-all seems to break words in the middle - is there a better way?

Comment: @codefactor OK, I found the solution, use table-layout: fixed; + word-wrap: break-word; and get rid of word-break: break-all; I also updated that into the answer above.